# How to show app data in erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, erb

A first look I thought erb accepts any Ruby code, but I've got this strange behaviour...

I have an array [of tags for my article], and I want to make a nice display for them. So I'm writing something like this:

```
<ul>
   <% @post.tags.each do |item| %> 
   <li>item</li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

The wrong output looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   ...
</ul>
```

Where I am wrong? Any suggestions how to make a proper iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `<%= %>` to display the value of `item`:

```
<ul>
   <% @post.tags.each do |item| %> 
   <li><%= item %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```